# Cocos2d ,need to include protocol in my implementation file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So basically I have a protocol inside my interface that I need to include in my implementation because I am getting an incomplete error and therefore can't continue.

. h file

```
@interface waveLayer1 : CCLayer <GameKitHelperProtocol>
{
    ...
}
```

.m file

```
@implementation waveLayer1
```

GameKitHelper.h file

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
@protocol GameKitHelperProtocol
-(void) onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged;
-(void) onFriendListReceived:   (NSArray*)friends;
-(void) onPlayerInfoReceived:(NSArray*)players;
@end

@interface GameKitHelper : NSObject {
    id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate; bool isGameCenterAvailable; NSError* lastError;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) bool isGameCenterAvailable; @property (nonatomic,    readonly) NSError* lastError;

+(GameKitHelper*) sharedGameKitHelper;
// Player authentication, info
-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer;
-(void) getLocalPlayerFriends;
-(void) getPlayerInfo:(NSArray*)players; 
@end
```

The error is "Method in protocol not implemented" I have more files I can show ,but to save room I decided to see if you can help me fix this with just these codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement these 3 methods in your waveLayer1 class..

```
-(void) onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged;
-(void) onFriendListReceived:(NSArray*)friends;
-(void) onPlayerInfoReceived:(NSArray*)players;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface waveLayer1 : CCLayer <GameKitHelperProtocol>
```

This says that "wavelayer1" implements the protocol "GameKitHelperProtocol".

```
Method in protocol not implemented
```

says that a method declared in a protocol has not been implemented. Chances are that you forgot to implement one of the "GameKitHelperProtocol" methods, which makes your class NOT implement that protocol, which violates the declaration you made, which causes the compiler to output an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare that a class adopts a protocol, you must write an implementation for all required methods that are defined in that protocol. So in this case, you need to add method implementations that are defined in `GameKitHelperProtocol`.